# How to get notes from Evernote with ajax than nodejs or sdk?

Tags: javascript, evernote

I want to get notes from Evernote, but I don't understand the APIs so much.
What I want to do is to use ajax to send data to Evernote, then get the data.

For example, use `$http` in Angular:

```
$http(options)
            .then(function ( data ) {
                console.log('Success');
            }, function ( reason ) {
                console.log('Error');
            });
```

Can I get notes use method like this ?

Comment: Have you seen the https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js docs?

Comment: Thank you. I think I have known how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed documentation on this topic can be found on [github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js](http://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js)